# Doubt Regarding cancellation of hotel in hostelworld.com

Tags: hotels, hostelworld

[image]
The above screenshot is from hostelworld.com, in the site it was mentioned free cancellation but while booking it again displayed Payable Now:US$49.46, so this amount we have to pay now to to reserve the room, if yes, after cancellation of that room can we get refund that paid amount of US$49.46.

Comment: What isn’t clear about the cancellation policy as stated in the screenshot?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if the cancellation is free, you get a refund of all amounts that you have prepaid.